# Node : How to display value to an input only if there is a value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

The add and update is happening on the same page, So initially all the input will be empty and when a data is click from the display page , all the data of the particular id should be displayed on all the inputs. 
But when I'm trying to do that using ternary opeartor if condition , it doesn't seem to work.

```
EJS

<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  name="landingTitle"
  value="<% result ? <%= result.landingTitle %> : '' %>" />
```

Backend

```
Node

// Initial Render
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("pages/dashboard");
});

//When the data is clicked for updation
router.get("/display/:id", (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.ATLAS_URI,
    { useNewUrlParser: true },
    (err, db) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const dbo = db.db("xxx");
      dbo
        .collection("xxx")
        .findOne({ _id: topic_id }, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.render("pages/dashboard", {
            result
          });
          db.close();
        });
    }
  );
});
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Any advise will be appreciated , Thank you

Comment: What is the error you are getting? If you click something on UI and you are loading the data with Ajax call, then yes it will not work as ejs only rendered once at serverside.

Comment: I'm not using ajax, I'm appending the value from backend using ejs directly . This is the error i'm getting-  Could not find matching close tag for "<%="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax issue here, please try the following and see if this works

```
value="<% if(result) { %> <%= result.landingTitle %> <% } else { %> '' <% } %>"
```

And if you are okay to use a non-inline version, you can always do the following

```
<%
 var value = (result && result.landingTitle)? result.landingTitle : '';
%>


<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  name="landingTitle"
  value="<%= value %>" 
/>
```

Comment: Wow, This fixed the syntax issue , But now i'm getting - result is not defined
 - error. Because in the initial page load i'm not passing result , but on click of update only i'm passing it , So how would I solve this

Comment: That is the question I was asking, If you get result on a user operation then that happens at the client-side, and you need to write js on client-side to make the call and fill the value.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more simple and clean way. Check if result is defined using `locals` object inside the conditional operator.

```
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="landingTitle"
    value="<%= locals.result ? result.landingTitle  : '' %>" 
/>
```

It will work, whether you render the `result` object or not.